# Holding my cats scruff

Tags: cats

I have a 3-year-old cat, pure white she-cat that has light blue eyes and she isn't deaf. a year ago I was able to pick her up by her scruff and she wouldn't show an emotion of minding it, i mostly do it if I'm giving her her yearly bath, or if she's fussy. But this year she will meow more if I hold her scruff, and she will show a sign of minding it, and when I set her down she will, if she's in my main room she would go behind the rocking chair, that's her spot, in the bath room she'll run beside the toilet, on the left side, or under the counter, and she'll normally meow to get out. I worry if I'm actually hurting her badly, because her sister is missing so I can't see if it happens to her as well, and I never got any hints on raising a cat, cause i got her for free, and I had no help raising them, because my brother wouldn't care, my mom would be busy with the dogs, and my stepdad will be busy being himself. Am i hurting her badly, or is she getting fussy that I hold her that way now, I held her like that for 2 1/2 years, and she didn't seem to mind until now, she will rarely not mind it, but I set her down 3 seconds later so I don't know her actions after those 3 seconds, and I really must know if I should stop or if it's a phase, cause like i said before i haven't held her sister like that when they were kits so i don't know if its only her.

Answer (score 0):

Older cats don't typically like being held that way, in our restraint training the scruff is one of the last ways we hold at cat as it puts them in a vulnerable position or just makes them mad. If being held in the air this way with no support on her bottom there can be discomfort, that's a lot of weight to be held by skin.

Be kind, hold your kitty with hands on chest and bum, she would appreciate it :)

Comment: thanks so much but i also have more questions now that i met people with more experience because i got the twins without even knowing how to hold them correctly and last time i held a full grown cat before i got my cats i got clawed on my shoulder is it bad to hold a cat like a baby? like craddling them, putting them on our shoulder, or setting them in our lap because i'm scared snowdrop will claw my scars and make them rebleed and i'm not sure if it makes her weak if i craddle her

Comment: It's not bad to hold a cat like a baby if they like it, some cats enjoy being on their backs while others don't. If she tries to fight her way out of being on her back then she doesn't like it.

You can always trim her nails if her claws hurt you as well (if she's an outdoor cat I don't recommend trimming nails).

No problems with having them on your shoulders or in your lap, many cats will do this.

Comment: thanks and i always wanted to know why my cat would go in the bathroom at night and meow at nothing. does she see her sisters spirit? is she calling out for her lost sister, calling for her kits we got rid of? i always worry because i call for her and she'll stop for a while then continue